# Tap & hold to show complete text in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uilabel, custom-view

I have a UILabel which do not show complete text due to limited frame (frame can't be changed); ellipsis is shown in the end.

I want to implement a feature wherein on tap and hold on UILabel, a pop-over with a magnifier appears and user is allowed to move his finger left/right to see the complete text. Release the tap will dismiss this custom view.

Comment: Possibly this control might work https://github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass  -- I just realized this control hasn't been updated in few years but might point you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks Yan. It seems this controls magnifies the tapped in view but does not allow you to see the NOT shown part in UILabel.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to just add a long press gesture recognizer and add a view on top of it with magnified and complete text. Why do you want to add a dependency for such a trivial thing?

Comment: I can go with this approach. Do you have any reference for such an implementation?

Comment: Hope this is helpful:- http://www.avocarrot.com/blog/implement-gesture-recognizers-swift/

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the UI you want but have you tried using

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Would make your life a lot easier. What you're trying to do is extremely complex.

Comment: Thanks David. I do not want to compromise on font size actually.